# Is it necessary to introduce ImplicitRegion and ParametricRegion in version 10?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, computational-geometry, geometry, regions

In version 10.0, *Mathematica* introduced a new function about region plotting: [ImplicitRegion](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html). But I'm wondered that haven't this function been already existed in the older version? That is, 
[RegionPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html). I truly can't see the difference.

Another question is, in version 10, *Mathematica* also introduced a function called [`ParametricRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html), my question is the same again: isn't it equivalent to the third usage of [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)?
PS: I found a little bit difference is that `ParametricRegion`(new function in ver. 10) have the ability to constrain the parameters in more specific way(not just required to be `{u,u_min,u_max}, {v,v_min,v_max}`, but also `{1 <= u <= 5, 3 <= v <= 10, u+v < 7.5}`), but it can seemingly be done by option `RegionFunction` in the older version!

Comment: There's a lot in *Mma* that, strictly speaking, isn't necessary.  But look at the `NDSolve`-FEM stuff, as well as integration, and you'll see that there are things that were difficult, perhaps impossible, to do before that can be done now.  The region functionality is part of the development of those capabilities.

Comment: For instance, you can't `Integrate` over `RegionPlot`, but you can do it over an `ImplicitRegion`. New computational geometry functionality with regions is more symbolic than old, which was mostly related to visualization. Sadly enough naming can be a bit confusing and prevent seeing the difference...

Comment: I would suggest that this Q is primarily opinion based or requires advice from Wolfram support, except I feel the answer is clearly yes.

Answer (score 10):

`ImplicitRegion` (and `ParametricRegion`) *represent* a region.  They are not for plotting.  Thus `RegionPlot` is not even remotely an alternative.

You can do many operations on regions that you can look up [in the documentation centre](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricPropertiesAndMeasures.html).  Just a few examples: you can compute their size, decide if a point is within, compute the distance between them, find their boundary, intersection, union, etc.  You can also integrate over regions numerically or symbolically, use them as a domain in several symbolic and numerical functions (e.g. optimization, PDE solving) or plotting functions.

All of these uses are completely unrelated to what `RegionPlot` can do.

Comment: So in older version, `RegionPlot` and `ParametricPlot` are just for plotting something, then can not be put altogether  with `Reduce`, `Solve`, such like [Solve >> Scope >> Geometric Region](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

Comment: And `RegionPlot`and `ParametricPlot` can have a lot of options to set its colors, aspect ratios, mesh styles and plot points, while `ImplicitRegion` and `ParametricRegion` cannot, since they are more likely to be treated as domain specification. However, they can be involved in equation/differential equation/inequalities solving, which is impossible to be done (directly) in the previous versions?

Comment: @Eric `RegionPlot` is for *visualizing* a region.  `ImplicitRegion` is for *representing* a region.  These are two entirely different purposes, and it makes little sense to compare the two functions.  You can use `RegionPlot` to plot any region object, e.g. `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2<1, {x,y}]]` or `RegionPlot[Disk[]]`.

Comment: @Eric, and you can have regions in 5D

Comment: I want to know whether `Integrate`(in version 10) can integrate on an arbitrary region such like triangles or ploygons(ie. 6-gon)? If possible, what's the algorithm inside kernel? It's pretty miraculous!